# Accumulate Daily data on weekly basis

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am new to excel formulas and macros. My sheet is show below.

```
id   Date      name   hours code    workPackage
1   3/28/2012   Anit    8   N1      1212
2   3/29/2012   Anit    8   N2      1212
3   3/30/2012   Anit    8   N2      1214
4   3/31/2012   Anit    8   N4      1212
5   4/1/2012    Anit    5   N1      1212
6   4/1/2012    Anit    3   N2      1212
7   4/3/2012    Anit    8   N2      1222
8   4/4/2012    Anit    8   N2      1212
9   4/5/2012    Anit    8   A1      1212
10  4/6/2012    Anit    8   A1      1212
```

I want to accumulate this daily data into a weekly (On fridays) based on Code and workPackage. For a particular Code and workpackage add the Hours for that week. The final output data should be something like this.

```
1   3/30/2012   Anit    8   N1      1212
2   3/30/2012   Anit    8   N2      1212
3   3/30/2012   Anit    8   N2      1214
4   4/6/2012    Anit    16  A1      1212
5   4/6/2012    Anit    5   N1      1212
6   4/6/2012    Anit    19  N2      1212
7   4/6/2012    Anit    8   N4      1212
```

If a query could be written by importing this data in a access DB or any other DB for the that, it would also be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ADO in Excel. The query would be:

```
Select Code, WorkPackage, Max([date]), First([Name]), Sum([Hours])
From [Sheet1$]
Group By Code, WorkPackage
```

Ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Edit re Comment

```
SELECT t.code, t.workPackage, Format([Date],"yyyy-ww") AS WeekNo, 
       Min(t.Date) AS MinOfDate, Max(t.Date) AS MaxOfDate, 
       Min(t.name) AS MinOfname, Sum(t.hours) AS SumOfhours
FROM [Sheet1$] t
GROUP BY t.code, t.workPackage, Format([Date],"yyyy-ww");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has helped me do half the things which i wanted to do.

Comment: your query doesn't give weekly data it gives the max date available. Can you help me out with it

Comment: It is not completely clear from your sample data what you want. i have added another example.

Comment: In my question Table 1 is daily data (see the dates). Table 2 sum of hours based on activity and workpackage of a particular week(every  Friday's - see the dates )

Comment: I imported all the data in access then I created a new table containing all fridays and this query worked as I wanted "SELECT time.Code, time.WorkPackage, dates.maxdate, First(time.[Name]) AS FirstOfStaffLastName, Sum(time.[Hours]) AS SumOfStaffHours FROM time, dates WHERE time.Date BETWEEN dates.mindate AND dates.maxdate GROUP BY time.Code, time.WorkPackage , dates.maxdate" Thanks for your help.